# How do I upgrade minion weapons?

Tags: impire

How do I upgrade my minion's weapons in Impire?

I've noticed that one of my groups' weapons have all upgraded, but I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this happens later in the game.  Beginning in chapter 2 you can upgrade weapons to blue.

When my one group's weapons were upgraded previously, they had been upgraded to gold.  I suspect this was done as a reward for one of the raid quests.